# how to display a link to individual microposts? (ruby on rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed a rails 3 tutorial and I'm trying to get this to work correctly.

All microposts that a user make is listed in `http://localhost:3000/users/username`

UsersController

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate page: params[:page], :per_page => 15
    end
```

Each micropost has an ID

```
create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string   "image"
    t.text     "comment_content"
  end
```

How can I set it up so that a link such as `http://localhost:3000/users/username/micropost_id` (if valid) will lead to page that has just that micropost?

I want the display to be exactly the same except show up individually on a new page.

Users table

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
  end
```

My config routes

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :authentications

resources :microposts, :path => "posts"


root to: 'static_pages#home'

            ActiveAdmin.routes(self)


  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts do
  resources :postcomments

end


  match '/signup',   to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/post',    to: 'static_pages#post'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/users/:username/:id', to: 'microposts#show', via: :get, as: :user_micropost
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a new route to your routes.rb file like the following:

```
match '/users/:username/:id', to 'microposts#show', via: :get, as: :user_micropost
```

and on the page that shows user's microposts, add the link as:

```
<a href="<%= user_micropost_path(username: @user.username, id: micropost.id) %>">Whatever..</a>
```

On the microposts controller, add the method show:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:id])
  # handle any errors from the code above
end
```

and create under

```
app/views/microposts/show.html.erb
```

the new page that will display the micropost.

Comment: I'm getting a `Couldn't find User with id=260`... how can I change it to search for the Micropost_Id.. not the userID? I updated the original post with the users schema

Comment: How did you add the link in the page that shows all posts? In your controller's "show" method, you should get the micropost's id via params[:id] and the username via params[:username]. Can you post the source of a generated link to see where it points?

Comment: actually I got it working. In the new `show.html.erb` that I just created inside the microposts folder, I have to create the view myself right? how can I reference just that particular micropost content, micropost user, etc to show?

Comment: Whatever variable you declare as member in the show method (using the @ as a prefix) will be available to the view. ex: `<span><%= @micropost.content %></span>` & in your controller's method: `@micropost = ...`

Comment: also, if someone not logged in tries to go to that link `http://localhost:3000/users/username/micropost_id`, it directs me back to the sign in page. Where can I add an exception/override that validation for those links and be available to the public?

Comment: I suppose you have something like :signed_in_user as a filter to your microposts controller. You should exclude that filter from the show method: change that line of your controller to `before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]` or whatever methods you want actually to be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your routes you have mention something like this

```
resources :users do
    resources :microposts
end
```

In that case you can create a link in your ***/views/users/show.html.erb***, something like this

```
<% @microposts.each do |post|
   <%= link_to truncate(post.content, :length => 10, :separator => '...'), user_micropost_path(@user, post) %>
<% end %>
```