# how to display individual listings? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working on a simple website where people can list postings. Most of the code is based on Michael Hartl's tutorial. 
I want users to have the ability to click on a link that displays the listing individually.
currently, the listings' of each user are found under

```
http://localhost:3000/users/id
```

Every listing has it's own id
Here are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :listings


  root 'static_pages#home'


  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new',          via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via:'delete'
  match '/help',      to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/contact',   to: 'static_pages#contact',  via: 'get'
  match '/about',     to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get' 
  match '/new',     to: 'listings#new',           via: 'get'
```

Here is my listing_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy, :edit]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)
    if @listing.save
        flash[:success] = "Job Post created"
        redirect_to current_user
        else
            render 'listings/new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def show
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])

    end

    def new
        @listing = Listing.new
        @listings = Listing.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

def destroy 
    @listing.destroy
    redirect_to current_user
end

private 

def listing_params
    params.require(:listing).permit(:description, :location, :title)
end

def correct_user
    @listing = current_user.listings.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to current_user if @listing.nil?
end

def current_listing
    @listings = listing.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

I also created a show page for each listing under listings the listings folder.
The show page itself works.
Here is the show.html.erb for the listing

```
<div class="show_listing">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><%= @listing.title %></h3>
        <h3><%= @listing.location %></h3>
        <p><%= @listing.description %></p><br>
        <div class="center">
        <%= link_to "Apply Now", '#', class: "btn btn-info", data: {no_turbolink: true} %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="show_link_position">
<% if current_user == @listing.user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', '#', class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', current_user, class: "btn btn-link" %>
</div>
```

Now I would like to have a link on the user page (under each listing) that would link to each post individually.

I'm looking for something like this
[how to display a link to individual microposts? (ruby on rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069733/how-to-display-a-link-to-individual-microposts-ruby-on-rails-3)

Thank you
Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to get it to work (with the help of the following stackoverflow post how to display a link to individual microposts? (ruby on rails 3))

Routes rb.

```
match '/users/:id/:id', to 'listings#show', via: :get, as: :user_listing
```

users view file

add the link

```
<li><%= link_to "Show", user_listing_path(id: @user.id, id: listing.id) %></li>
```

Changed my listing_controller file

```
def show
            @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
            @listing = Listing.find_by_id(params[:id])

        end
```

Comment: I think you have a problem.  This suggests that the user's ID and the listing ID are the same???  You'd typically have something like `'/users/:user_id/:id'` so that your controller can find those in `params` separately.

Comment: hm... I am not sure. It's working though. The User Id and Listing ID also shouldn't be the same. There is a table for listings and a table for users. Listings and Users have their own id's.

Answer (score 1):

To create a link from a page where you have the collection of listings as `@listings`, you might have something like this...

```
<ol class="listings">
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <div class="listing">
      <h2><%= listing.title</h2>
      <h3><%= listing.location</h3>
      <p><%= listing.description</p>
      <%= link_to "Show", listing, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: that's a good idea but I would like to link to each individual listing.  The listing consists of title location and description

Comment: The code I proposed would emit a "list" of links to all of the listings in the @listing collection.  Did you try what I proposed?

Comment: I would like to create a link (positioned under each listing in the listings collection that says show) which when clicked would open a new show page that shows just that one particular listing.
I tried your proposal and it creates a list of links with the title of the listings but thats not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: OK... I just tried to keep the answer brief and focused on the essential matter of getting the link.  I figured you could add the rest of the listing yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't get it that quickly but I'm very new to Rails. When I use the link I get the following error
undefined local variable or method `listing'

Comment: Can you post the controller and view for the user page that you're working on?  You could even throw it up in a Gist?

Comment: Here is the the link to the Gist
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3662ad77ccad3b03284
I posted the user controller and user show/view code.

Comment: I'm sorry but what did you change?

Comment: click the "edited ... mins ago" button to see the diff.  (I didn't change much.)  What I had previously should still work.

Comment: You mean this yes?

<ol class="listings">
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
    <div class="listing">
      <h2><%= listing.title</h2>
      <h3><%= listing.location</h3>
      <p><%= listing.description</p>
      <%= link_to "Show", listing, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</ol>

Comment: Okay I got it to work. I posted what I did above.
Thank you for your help.