# Displaying only unique values and many associated values on a html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my current page view below:

```
<%= link_to "Back", root_path, :class => "pull-right time-padding" "btn btn-primary btn-sm"%>
<div class="entries">
   <% @entries.each do |entry| %>
   <h2><%= link_to entry.competition.name, entries_path %></h2>
   <li><%= link_to entry.competitor.full_name %></li>
   <br/>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

I would like to display only unique `entry.competition.name` and then all the associated `entry.competitor.fullname`. Currently it loops over every entry of both and displays them.

I checked [how to display individual listings? Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150158/how-to-display-individual-listings-ruby-on-rails) and [how to display a link to individual microposts? (ruby on rails 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069733/how-to-display-a-link-to-individual-microposts-ruby-on-rails-3), but am not sure how those connect to the function I am seeking.

I am looking at `link_to entry.competition.name.uniq`, but I cannot grok how to implement something like this.

Comment: Can you include the controller code that set up the @entries variable as well as the models for Competition and Competitors. My hunch is that you really want to loop over each competition (rather than each entry) and then show the list of competitors per competition.

Comment: @RobDiMarco the     `def show
      @entries = Entry.where.not('competition_id' => nil)
      # @entries = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end`  I would like to do that, however I think the merge table complicates that, at least for my new ruby brain. `class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitions
  has_many :lifts
  has_many :entries

  def full_name
    [f_name, l_name].join(" ")
  end
end`
Here is the competition model --> `class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitors
  has_many :lifts
  has_many :entries
end
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get one value for each competition name:

```
@entries.reduce({}){|m,e| m[e.competition.name] = e.competition; m}.values
```

You can do likewise for full.name